# Img src doesn't display with echo in php multilanguage

Tags: javascript, php, echo, multilingual

There are 2 different languages on my website, one of them is English and the other is German. English and German words are obtained via en.php and gr.php. Especially when paragraph `<p>` is like `<h1>`, there is no trouble. Codes work. However, when I want to put a video, I want to do a src problem. English video on English page. I want the German video to come when the German page is opened. And I want to get it from en.php and gr.php. What should I write in src?
 `<h5> <?php echo $lang['hello']; ?> </h5>` when it works. I want to open another video on YouTube, for example, when it comes to English, and another video on YouTube when it appears in Germany.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/gkleklgem"
        gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

en.php

```
<?php
$lang['hello']      = 'Hello';
?>
```

gr.php

```
 <?php
$lang['hello']      = 'Hallo';
?>
```

Comment: not clear what you're asking. Can you give an example of how the url to the video would change? (You are missing a `"` in the iframe-src by the way)

Comment: just as you did 'hello' it could be `$lang['videoSrc'] = 'gkleklgem';`

Comment: I rewrote the code

Comment: I have tried but not working

Comment: you need to show what you've tried and tell us what exactly is _"not working"_. Is there an error? Is the url pasted correctly or not? ...?

Answer (score 2):

You can put url of english video version into your en.php and then in accordance german version into gr.php

And after that, like you did before with 'hello' write something like that:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?= $lang['videoUrl']?>" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: my page works best when it comes to the page but does not work when it comes to gr

Comment: what exactly is not working? can you provide more detailed info?